# Trouble Writing a display method

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, methods

Please give a look and if you can, a bit of guidance.

```
public class VacationScale {

    int [] vacationDays;

    int yearsOfService;

    public void setVacationScale() {

        vacationDays = new int[7];

        vacationDays[0] = 10;
        vacationDays[1] = 15;
        vacationDays[2] = 15;
        vacationDays[3] = 15;
        vacationDays[4] = 20;
        vacationDays[5] = 20;
        vacationDays[6] = 25;

        public static void displayvacationDays(){
            if(yearsOfService >=0){
                System.out.println("Vacation days " + vacationDays[yearsOfService]);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid years of service");
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Everything is fine until I write the method, eclipse is telling me that

"Illegal modifier for parameter displayvacationDays; only final is permitted"

and obviously when i try final it doesn't not work either. ( I knew final wouldn't work, i just thought id try it though)

```
public static void displayvacationDays(){

      if(yearsOfService >=0){
          System.out.println("Vacation days " + vacationDays[yearsOfService]);
      }
      else {
          System.out.println("Invalid years of service");
      }
}
```

Any thoughts on how I can get this method to work?

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing instance data from within public static void displayvacationDays(){. So, declare as non-static:

```
public void c(){..}
```

not as:

```
public static void displayvacationDays(){..}
```

And, also have setVacationScale function as a separate function, no nesting

Answer (score 0):

In the first code you posted `displayvacationDays()` is contained within the `setVacationScale()` method.

If that's your real code, and not some copy and paste error, move it outside that method.

In addition, either make `vacationDays` and `setVacationScale()` both static, or don't make `displayvacationDays()` static.

Comment: You my friend, have just saved me hours. Thank you. Can't believe how simple that was. Bad error on my behalf.

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare a method within a method. Do like this :

```
int [] vacationDays;

int yearsOfService;

public void setVacationScale() {

    vacationDays = new int[7];

    vacationDays[0] = 10;
    vacationDays[1] = 15;
    vacationDays[2] = 15;
    vacationDays[3] = 15;
    vacationDays[4] = 20;
    vacationDays[5] = 20;
    vacationDays[6] = 25;
}

public void displayvacationDays(){

    if(yearsOfService >=0)
    {
        System.out.println("Vacation days " + vacationDays[yearsOfService]);
     }
     else
     {
         System.out.println("Invaild years of service");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- The declaration of the method `displayvacationDays` is misplaced (within the declaration of the method `setVacationScale`)
- `displayvacationDays` should be non-static, as it works with the instance's variables.

Corrected code:

```
public class VacationScale {

    int[] vacationDays;
    int yearsOfService;

    public void setVacationScale () {

        vacationDays = new int[7];

        vacationDays[0] = 10;
        vacationDays[1] = 15;
        vacationDays[2] = 15;
        vacationDays[3] = 15;
        vacationDays[4] = 20;
        vacationDays[5] = 20;
        vacationDays[6] = 25;
    }

    public void displayvacationDays () {
        if (yearsOfService >= 0) {
            System.out.println("Vacation days " + vacationDays[yearsOfService]);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invaild years of service");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Saved me a lot of time. I can not believe how simple that was. Bad mistake on my behalf. Thank you once again.